# sequence convergence proof $\{ \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

$\{ \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\}$

Idk how to do this but my attempt:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $\left| \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} - 1 \right| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose $N = $ _____ > 0

Suppose $n > N$, then $$= \left|\frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\right|$$

I don't know what to go from here

Comment: Hint: use $(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\cdot (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})=1$

Comment: Thank you, that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $N=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$.

Thus, for all $n>N$ we have $$\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)>2n>\frac{1}{\epsilon},$$ which gives
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}<\epsilon$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$$ or
$$\left|\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}-1\right|<\epsilon,$$
which says that our sequence converges to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to go forward is to multiply the expression by $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Or divide by $\sqrt{n} $ on top and bottom. ..  get $\frac {\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}{1} $, which goes to  $\frac {\sqrt {1+0}}{1}$, or $1$.  So you may choose N large enough that  $\bigg|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{N}}-1\bigg|< \epsilon $.Then do a little algebra to get how large  N has to be  in terms of $\epsilon$...  Get $N>\frac {1}{2\epsilon +\epsilon^2}$.